# sound.pos() Howler method returns object but I need an integer or string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, casting, howler.js

I am trying to output the current track time to an HTML page using Howler, but at the moment it's just displaying [Object object]. The relevant code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var position = 0;
    var sound = new Howl({
        src: ["audiofiles/" + $(xml).find('mp3').text()],
        autoplay: true,
        loop: true,
        volume: 0.5,
            onload: function () {
                console.log("LOADED");
            }
        });
        // Output and update current track time as song plays
        position = sound.pos();
        document.getElementById("current_time").innerHTML = position;
```

How do I extract the track time info in a format that's useful for outputting to the HTML page? Preferably like this: [mm/ss].

I have also tried `sound.seek()` which also outputs an object.

Calling `toString()` on the `position` variable yields: [object Undefined] when the HTML is loaded into the browser, and calling `JSON.stringify()` on it just results in what I assume to be empty string (outputs nothing to webpage whatsoever).

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using howler.js 2.0, which changed the API to use `seek()` rather than `pos()`. However, this is just going to get the seek value at that point in time, you are responsible for updating it in your HTML at the pace that you want (take a look at the player [example](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/blob/master/examples/player/player.js)).

The relevant code from the example tweaked for your scenario:

```
function step() {
  // Get the current position and format it however you would like.
  var seek = sound.seek() || 0;
  document.getElementById("current_time").innerHTML = self.formatTime(Math.round(seek));

  // Update the value on each frame.
  if (sound.playing()) {
    requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }
}
```